# Monitoring of process creation and termination

Tags: c#, .net

I try to monitor the creation and termination of any processes without having admin rights!
I found the many posted examples like this one:

```
// query every 2 seconds
string pol = "2";

WqlEventQuery queryString = new WqlEventQuery(
    "SELECT *" +
    "  FROM __InstanceOperationEvent " +
    "WITHIN  " + pol +
    " WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' ");

// You could replace the dot by a machine name to watch to that machine
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\CIMV2");

// create the watcher and start to listen
watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, queryString);
watcher.EventArrived += OnEventArrived;
watcher.Start();
```

If I only receive the event I can determine if a process was started or stopped, but if I try to consume the `e.NewEvent.Property["ProcessName"].Value` in `OnEventArrived` I get in trouble with the access rights.

My question is now:
Why can I receive information about the creation and termination in general, but if I want to get details out of the Event I become restricted?

I can use `Process.GetProcesses()` and compare that information with any previous values I get on my own, so I can get this information anyway. It doesn't seem like I should need access rights.

Comment: A Powershell script would be considerable option instead of C# for monitoring processes...

Comment: @JDavila yes if you have no customer that would like to see a little green sign in the application for all processes he would like to monitor ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To access certain processes, there must be admin rights created for that specific process, or an admin account that exists within the group that can access the processes in concern.

"You cannot access process resources through the process name alone but, once you have retrieved an array of Process components that have been associated with the process resources, you can start, terminate, and otherwise manipulate the system resources."

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx

Essentially, an array of processes must be created in a C# array to access and modify the processes.

The details of the process most likely require a higher access level or permissions. Access to objects are based on different levels, such as information, error, etc. Typically, with Windows Authentication, the user needs access rights to that object before any other type of modification can occur.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but you know that's even possible to get the commandline parameter of any running process and so I don't know why there is no easy way to get informed that e.g. notepad.exe was started without admin rights or setting up a Watcher for each filename I would like to monitor.